# Does Flutter have widgets other than material and cupertino?

Tags: flutter

As far as I know Flutter have build in widget system that named `material` and `cupertino`. But is there any other widgets sets. I want to build site with Flutter but do not want to make it look as mobile app.

Comment: hey there, if my answer helped you out please make sure to accept it as valid answer :)

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't any other widget set. Flutters `material` and `cupertino` are ment to get your app a native look. **They don't have any special functionality than visual design.**

If you just want to do your own styling and elements, you can build your widgets by your own. You can read more about it here:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/10126984-creating-reusable-custom-widgets-in-flutter